# MODIS MOD10A2 snow product

Tags: remote-sensing, interpolation, modis

I have extracted pixel value ( pixel value=200 for snow) from MOD10A2 snow product for my study area.
Since MOD10A2 product is distributed every 8-days. i.e., 9th Jan, 17th Jan, 25th Jan,2nd Feb,.... I need to have daily snow cover area to input for the model. 
However, some papers have mentioned about the linear interpolation technique to determine the snow cover area of missing days between to give date. 
I am looking for your kind help to solve my problem, so I have the snow  cover area on daily basis to get snow depletion curve.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite tricky to interpolate based on the MOD10A2 because this is a maximum extent product (1 snow observation and seven non snow observation is flagged as snow). I would rather recommend you to use the [daily products](http://nsidc.org/data/docs/daac/mod10a1_modis_terra_snow_daily_global_500m_grid.gd.html).

Comment: I have read some paper that MOD10A2 is better than MOD10A1 ( daily) as earlier deals with cloud coverage.I even used daily product to generate SCA but the depletion curve doesn't look like that I see in some papers , specially in terms of shape. Hope you got what I mean to express.